# DataGrid CellEditEnding For Commits and Validation

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a datagrid (using WPFToolKit), which contain some columns that are editable.
I have to put some validation on entry that user inputs. 
I have done this with the help of event.:

```
datagrid1_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
```

Can someone tell me how to commit or not commit the data that is provided by user?

How end the event when validation is done ?

Answer (score 1):

Try commiting in the `CurrentCellChanged` event as mentioned here:
http://blog.scottlogic.com/2009/01/21/wpf-datagrid-committing-changes-cell-by-cell.html

Answer (score 0):

You can cancel the edit operation by executing the Method "CancelEdit" on the data grid itself. This even will also roll up to the DataSource that the grid is bound to.

If you cancel, the data won't be committed. To manually commit you will have to fire up the Save, Submit or SubmitChanges method (depending on the DataContext/DataSource that you are using...)

I use LinqToSql with WPF, it uses SubmitChanges to save and I also use the property GetChangeSet to inspect the changes that were made to the context before saving.

Regards
Q

Comment: it is throwing System.StackOverflowException

Comment: you can use code from http://codefluff.blogspot.co.il/2010/05/commiting-bound-cell-changes.html to avoid StackOverflow.